# How to unit test code involving SynchronizationContext?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

I have following code that I'm trying to test using NUnit and Rhino mocks.

```
void _tracker_IndexChanged(object sender, IndexTrackerChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //  _context is initialised as 
    //  SynchronizationContext _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    // _tracker.Index is stubbed to return the value 100
    _context.Post(o => _view.SetTrackbarValue(_tracker.Index), null);
}
```

In testcase I have set the expectation as

```
_view.Expect(v => v.SetTrackbarValue(100));
```

and when I verify expectation, the unit test fails randomaly with message

```
Test(s) failed. Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException :
IIndexTrackerView.SetTrackbarValue(100); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

I failed identify the problem here, How do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually solve problems like this by encapsulating global state with an abstract class or interface that can be instanced and mocked out.  Then instead of directly accessing the global state, I inject an instance of my abstract class or interface into the code that uses it.

This lets me mock out the global behavior, and makes it so my tests don't depend on or exercise that unrelated behavior.

Here's one way you could do that.

```
public interface IContext
{
    void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state);
}

public class SynchronizationContextAdapter : IContext
{
    private SynchronizationContext _context;

    public SynchronizationContextAdapter(SynchronizationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public virtual void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
    {
        _context.Post(d, state);
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(IContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    void _tracker_IndexChanged(object sender, IndexTrackerChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _context.Post(o => _view.SetTrackbarValue(_tracker.Index), null);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then you can mock or stub out `IContext` so you don't have to worry about threading, and can use a simple implementation that just executes the delegate.

If I wrote unit tests to mock this out, I'd also write higher level "integration" tests that didn't mock it out, but had less granular verifications.

Comment: +1, but really want to make sure `_view.SetTrackbarValue` is called!

Comment: @Prashant: Then I'd definitely stub out the "context" class rather then mocking it.  Have it directly call the delegate that is passed to it.  In your unit test, set your expectation on the view rather than on the context class.  Couple this test with a few simple UI-based integration tests to make sure you don't get any weird errors when substituting the real `SynchronizationContext` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Rhino Mocks in a while so I can't remember the exact syntax but if refactoring things as Merlyn suggests is not an option then another solution would be to use a ManualResetEvent to wait until your mock has been acted on.

Something like this:

```
[Test]
public void ATest(){
  ManualResetEvent completed = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  _view.Expect(v => v.SetTrackbarValue(100)).Do(() => completed.Set());
  //Stuff done here...   
  Assert.IsTrue(completed.WaitOne(1000), "Waited a second for a call that never arrived!");

}
```

That way you can wait until the other thread triggers the event, at which point you can continue. Make sure there is a sensible timeout so you dont wait forever though!

Comment: Why do you think that it will be the other thread which will update the View? I think it will be the same thread which will halt on `WaitOne` statement.

Comment: @Snowbear - If the thread calling post on the SynchronisationContext is the same thread that is running the test then this approach obviously wont work. I'm going on the fact that a SynchronisationContext is being used to make the assumption it is running on a separate thread.